# Sorting within a Pandas group without changing group position

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to sort within a pandas group without actually changing the group position in the Dataframe.

The original dataframe is in this format:

```
    group   name  revenue
0  GroupB  Name1        1
1  GroupB  Name2        2
2  GroupB  Name3        3
3  GroupA  Name4        4
4  GroupA  Name5        5
5  GroupA  Name6        6
```

And I am trying to achieve the following output:

```
    group   name  revenue
0  GroupB  Name3        3
1  GroupB  Name2        2
2  GroupB  Name1        1
3  GroupA  Name6        6
4  GroupA  Name5        5
5  GroupA  Name4        4
```

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Name1','Name2','Name3','Name4','Name5','Name6'], 
    'group':['GroupB','GroupB','GroupB','GroupA','GroupA','GroupA'],'revenue':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})

def sort_group(grp):
    grp = grp.sort(columns='revenue',ascending=False)
    return grp

df = df.groupby('group').apply(sort_group)

print df
```

The result I get is:

```
           group   name  revenue
group
GroupA 5  GroupA  Name6        6
       4  GroupA  Name5        5
       3  GroupA  Name4        4
GroupB 2  GroupB  Name3        3
       1  GroupB  Name2        2
       0  GroupB  Name1        1
```

Essentially, my current code shifts Group B under Group A, but I want Group B to remain at the top.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
df.sort(['group', 'revenue'], ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

It gives me

```
    group   name    revenue
0   GroupB  Name3   3
1   GroupB  Name2   2
2   GroupB  Name1   1
3   GroupA  Name6   6
4   GroupA  Name5   5
5   GroupA  Name4   4
```

Comment: Thanks Kikohs, that was simpler than I thought. Can you explain why adding the 'group' as the first sorting argument leaves it as is?

Comment: It doesn't, it sorts in descending order. GroupC would appear first if it was here. If you want to specifically have groupB always on top, you can then use the reindex method and provide a custom index with rows of groupB on top.

Comment: Ah so it just happened that alphabetically it worked. Could you point me in the right direction of what type of custom method would achieve this?

Comment: You can use DataFrame.reindex, http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html 

You supply a new index and the dataframe you will change accordingly.