# Sort within group without changing group order?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Can't seem to find an up-to-date answer on this online. Problem I have is essentially the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808355/sorting-within-a-pandas-group-without-changing-group-position), that is, I want to sort by say `revenue` within `group` without changing the order of `group` in my dataset.

The answer to that thread is wrong, it works only because there were just two groups in the example which happened to be anti-alphabetically ordered.

When I try `df.groupby('group').sort_values('revenue')`, I get error `'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'sort_values'`.

How can I do this?

Sample DataFrame:

```
    name    group   revenue
0   Name1   GroupB  1
3   Name4   GroupA  4
4   Name5   GroupA  5
8   Name7   GroupC  9
1   Name2   GroupB  2
2   Name3   GroupB  3
5   Name6   GroupA  6
6   Name7   GroupC  7
7   Name7   GroupC  8
```

Expected Output:

```
    name   group  revenue
2  Name3  GroupB        3
1  Name2  GroupB        2
0  Name1  GroupB        1
5  Name6  GroupA        6
4  Name5  GroupA        5
3  Name4  GroupA        4
8  Name7  GroupC        9
7  Name7  GroupC        8
6  Name7  GroupC        7
```

Comment: What order do you want the groups to be in? The same order as in the input? Or sorted some other way than in the answer on the linked post (e.g. increasing instead of decreasing)?

Comment: "without changing the order of group in my dataset."  same order as input. as asked in the thread I linked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a new temporary column that transforms `B`, `A` and `C` to `1`, `2` and `3`, so that you maintain order of the unordered. Then, just drop the temporary column. In Answer #1, this is more dynamic and will work if the `group` column values are not grouped together consecutively. For Answer #2, they must be consecutive (the inputs for answer #1 and answer #2 are ordered differently)

**Updated Answer #1** (per comment - the groups are not consecutive in rows, but we still want to order them correctly by the order of appearance of the first value within each group.) The code `[l for l  in enumerate((df['group'].unique()))]` will assign a number to each group depending on the order of the first value of the `group` column in the dataframe.

```
In[1]:
    name    group   revenue
0   Name1   GroupB  1
3   Name4   GroupA  4
4   Name5   GroupA  5
8   Name7   GroupC  9
1   Name2   GroupB  2
2   Name3   GroupB  3
5   Name6   GroupA  6
6   Name7   GroupC  7
7   Name7   GroupC  8

dft = pd.DataFrame([l for l  in enumerate((df['group'].unique()))], columns=['group_number','group'])
df = pd.merge(df, dft, how='left', on='group').sort_values(['group_number', 'revenue'], ascending = [True, False])
df

Out[1]: 
    name   group  revenue  group_number
5  Name3  GroupB        3             0
4  Name2  GroupB        2             0
0  Name1  GroupB        1             0
6  Name6  GroupA        6             1
2  Name5  GroupA        5             1
1  Name4  GroupA        4             1
3  Name7  GroupC        9             2
8  Name7  GroupC        8             2
7  Name7  GroupC        7             2
```

I wanted to highlight the output of `dft` of the `enumerate` line of code before the merge and sort.

```
dft = pd.DataFrame([l for l  in enumerate((df['group'].unique()))], columns=['group_number','group'])
dft

Out[2]: 
   group_number   group
0             0  GroupB
1             1  GroupA
2             2  GroupC
```

---

Answer  #2

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Name1','Name2','Name3','Name4','Name5','Name6', 'Name7', 'Name7', 'Name7'], 
    'group':['GroupB','GroupB','GroupB','GroupA','GroupA','GroupA','GroupC','GroupC','GroupC'],'revenue':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})
df['cs'] = (df['group'] != df['group'].shift(1)).cumsum()
df = df.sort_values(['cs', 'revenue'], ascending = [True, False])
df
Out[11]: 
    name   group  revenue  cs
2  Name3  GroupB        3   1
1  Name2  GroupB        2   1
0  Name1  GroupB        1   1
5  Name6  GroupA        6   2
4  Name5  GroupA        5   2
3  Name4  GroupA        4   2
8  Name7  GroupC        9   3
7  Name7  GroupC        8   3
6  Name7  GroupC        7   3
```

---

For both answers, then just drop the column:

```
df = df.drop('cs', axis=1)

Out[12]: 
    name   group  revenue
2  Name3  GroupB        3
1  Name2  GroupB        2
0  Name1  GroupB        1
5  Name6  GroupA        6
4  Name5  GroupA        5
3  Name4  GroupA        4
8  Name7  GroupC        9
7  Name7  GroupC        8
6  Name7  GroupC        7
```

Comment: Thanks. This assumes the groups are together to start with. What if they aren't, e.g. the groups are randomly distributed? Is there a way to first sort by order of appearance in the column, then carry out what you just did?

Comment: how would you define the order of appearance if they are not grouped together?  By the first value?

Comment: Yes, the first one that occurred in the column

Comment: @MobeusZoom see me update (Answer #1). Answer #2 is the old answer from earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Why use groupby at all? You could just chain together multiple sort_values calls to get the correct sort order. e.g. using similar data to linked question and you wanted to sort by revenue descending but maintain groups ascending you could do:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Name1','Name2','Name3','Name4','Name5','Name6', 'Name7', 'Name7', 'Name7'], 
    'group':['GroupB','GroupB','GroupB','GroupA','GroupA','GroupA','GroupC','GroupC','GroupC'],'revenue':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})

df.sort_values(by='revenue', ascending= False).sort_values(by='group')
```

Which would return:

```
name    group   revenue
5   Name6   GroupA  6
4   Name5   GroupA  5
3   Name4   GroupA  4
2   Name3   GroupB  3
1   Name2   GroupB  2
0   Name1   GroupB  1
8   Name7   GroupC  9
7   Name7   GroupC  8
6   Name7   GroupC  7
```

Comment: In your example, the groups should be ordered B, A, C