# Sort dataframe with another one

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which I am currently first splitting into a training and test set

```
import pandas as pd

X = df.drop(['label'], axis=1)
y = df['label']

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25)
```

with the usual code from `scikitlearn`. This random shuffling is necessary. Next I want to sort `X_train` and `X_val` by a certain variable (let's say `revenue` as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63531296/sort-within-group-without-changing-group-order/63531589#63531589)).

The problem with `X_train.sort_values('revenue')` is that after I do this, I have no way to sort `y_train` such that the labels correctly match up with `X_train` rows.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Maybe sort data before split?

Comment: this should work y_train.reindex(X_train.index)

Comment: As dibery pointed out, you can drop the y column at the very end... `train_test_split` works with either one ore two arrays (X, y or just df[X+y])

Answer (score 1):

One way doing is to reindex the other dataframe based on the index of the sorted dataframe. You can use the following example for reference :

```
In [99]: df                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[99]: 
     key  lower  upper
0  panda     10     15
1    dog      7      9
2    cat      8     17

In [100]: X = df.drop(['key'],axis=1)                                                                                                                                             

In [101]: y = df['key']                                                                                                                                                           

In [102]: X.sort_values('lower',inplace=True)                                                                                                                                     

In [103]: test = y.reindex(X.index)                                                                                                                                               

In [104]: X                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[104]: 
   lower  upper
1      7      9
2      8     17
0     10     15

In [105]: test                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[105]: 
1      dog
2      cat
0    panda
Name: key, dtype: object
```